# Convert vowels from upper case to lower case and lower case to upper case using sed

Tags: linux, string, sed

I would need to create a script that uses sed to replace the lower case vowels with upper case vowels and the upper case vowels with lover case ones.
For example if I would have the string "This Is a lOng String" the result should be "ThIs is A long StrIng".
I tried something like this `sed 's/a/A/g ; s/A/a/g'` but this will not change a->A and A->a it only replaces the lower case ones.. 
I know there were similar questions but I couldn't get it to work so I thought I would ask you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sed`'s `y` command for transliterating.

```
sed 'y/aeiouAEIOU/AEIOUaeiou/'
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ echo "This Is a lOng String" | sed 'y/aeiouAEIOU/AEIOUaeiou/'
ThIs is A long StrIng
```

Answer (score 3):

Why restrict yourself to sed?  A quick test on my box has:

```
$ tr 'aeiouAEIOU' 'AEIOUaeiou'
```

running almost 6 times faster than the equivalent sed command.  (And redirecting output to the bit bucket, tr is 135 times faster, outputting to a pipe has tr 38.5 times faster.  Sure, these are single test benchmarks and are not at all accurate, but tr is the right tool for this.)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 'y/aeiouAEIOU/AEIOUaeiou/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement this, from lower to upper:

```
sed 'y/aeiou/AEIOU/' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```